# generating pdfs from google sheets by app script : need a faster method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf

**The code which i am using in appscript is**

```
function generateAndSaveInvoice() {
  
  // Getting the active sheets
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheetNew = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(<someID>));

  // Loading the sheets
  var deliveryNote = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(<SomeName>);
  var dataSheet = dataSheetNew.getSheetByName(<SomeName>);

  // Retrieve data values
  var dataValues = dataSheet.getSheetValues(1,1,dataSheetNew.getLastRow(), dataSheetNew.getLastColumn());

  // setting the drive folder
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(<SomeName>);
  

  // Iterate through rows
  for (var i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    var netTon = dataValues[i][4];
    var vehicleNumber = dataValues[i][2];
    var noteNo = dataValues[i][0];

    // Update the values
    updateInvoiceCells(deliveryNote,vehicleNumber,netTon,noteNo);

    // Generate PDF 
    saveDeliveryNoteAsPDF(pdfFolder, 'DeliveryNote_' + i, noteNo);
    
  }
}



function updateInvoiceCells(invoiceSheet, vehicleNumber, netTon, noteNo) {
  Logger.log("Updating with values - Vehicle Number: " + vehicleNumber + ", Net Ton: " + netTon + ", Note No: " + noteNo);

  // Update cells I11 and G14 with the provided data
  invoiceSheet.getRange(<SomeValue>).setValue(vehicleNumber);
  invoiceSheet.getRange(<SomeValue>).setValue(netTon);
  invoiceSheet.getRange(<SomeValue>).setValue("Delivery Note No : " + noteNo);

  Logger.log("Updated Sheet ");
}



function saveDeliveryNoteAsPDF(pdfFolder, fileName, noteNo) {
  // Create a copy of the active spreadsheet
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copiedSpreadsheet = originalSpreadsheet.copy('Copy of ' + originalSpreadsheet.getName());

  // Generate the PDF using the copied sheet's range
  var pdfBlob = copiedSpreadsheet.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

  // Save the PDF to the specified folder
  var pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName + '.pdf');

  // Delete the copied spreadsheet to avoid cluttering Google Drive
  DriveApp.getFileById(copiedSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

  Logger.log("Saved DeliveryNote No " + noteNo);
}
```

The code is working fine but it takes very long to generate the PDF, so needed a solution which could probably fasten the whole process of generating pdf.

Major time is consumed in copying the spreadsheet and deleting it.